# Process for Showing Sufficiency for Normal Distribution

Tags: statistics

Problem:

$X_1, X_2...X_n\sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$, Let $T=(\bar{X}, S)$. Show that T is a sufficient using factorization theorem.

I mostly get it, but there a few steps in the given solution that I find confusing. I will highlight them with an under-brace.

$f(X^n|\mu,\sigma)=\prod_{i=1}^n\Bigg[\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\bigg(\frac{-1}{2\sigma^2}(X-\mu)^2\bigg)\Bigg]=\bigg(\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}\bigg)^n\cdot\frac{1}{\sigma^n}\exp\bigg(\frac{-1}{2\sigma^2}\sum_{i=1}^n(X-\mu)^2\bigg)$

First question: Where does the "$\frac{1}{\sigma^n}$" come from?

Moving along:

= $\bigg(\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}\bigg)^n\cdot\frac{1}{\sigma^n}\exp\bigg(\frac{-1}{2\sigma^2}\Bigg[\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i-\mu)^2-n\bar{X}^2+n\bar{X}^2\Bigg]\bigg)$

=$\bigg(\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}\bigg)^n\cdot\frac{1}{\sigma^n}\exp\bigg(\frac{-1}{2\sigma^2}\Bigg[\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i^2-2\mu X_i+\mu^2)-n\bar{X}^2+n\bar{X}^2\Bigg]\bigg)$

And distributing the summations

= $\bigg(\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}\bigg)^n\cdot\frac{1}{\sigma^n}\exp\bigg(\frac{-1}{2\sigma^2}\Bigg[\sum_{i=1}^nX_i^2-\underbrace{2\mu}_{???} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i+n\mu^2-n\bar{X}^2+n\bar{X}^2\Bigg]\bigg)$

Question 2, as indicated in the underbrace: Why did the distribution of the summations NOT put an n coefficient next to the $\mu$?

= $\bigg(\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}\bigg)^n\cdot\frac{1}{\sigma^n}\exp\bigg(\frac{-1}{2\sigma^2}\Bigg[\sum_{i=1}^nX_i^2-n\bar{X^2}+2\mu \sum_{i=1}^n X_i+n\mu^2+n\bar{X}^2\Bigg]\bigg)$

=$\bigg(\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}\bigg)^n\cdot\frac{1}{\sigma^n}\exp\bigg(\frac{-1}{2\sigma^2}\Bigg[\phantom{.} n\cdot \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nX_i^2-n\bar{X^2}+2\mu \cdot  \phantom{.} n\cdot \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i+n\mu^2+n\bar{X}^2\Bigg]\bigg)$

=$\bigg(\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}\bigg)^n\cdot\frac{1}{\sigma^n}\exp\bigg(\frac{-1}{2\sigma^2}\Bigg[\phantom{.} n\bigg( \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nX_i^2-\bar{X}^2\bigg)+2\mu \cdot  \phantom{.} n\cdot \bigg(\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i\bigg)+n\mu^2+n\bar{X}^2\Bigg]\bigg)$

=  $\bigg(\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}\bigg)^n\cdot\frac{1}{\sigma^n}\exp\bigg(\frac{-1}{2\sigma^2}\Bigg[\phantom{.} n\bigg( \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nX_i^2-\bar{X}^2\bigg)+\bigg(\underbrace{-2}_{???}\mu n\bar{X}+n\mu^2+n\bar{X}^2\bigg)\Bigg]\bigg)$

Question 3, as indicated in the underbrace. Where did this negative sign come from?

The rest of the solution I understand, as long as I can understand why these three elements are true...

Comment: You should do this yourself without relying on the solution by starting from $\prod_{i=1}^n \frac1{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left[-\frac1{2\sigma^2}(x_i-\mu)^2\right]=\frac1{(\sigma\sqrt{2\pi})^n}\exp\left[-\frac1{2\sigma^2}\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-\mu)^2\right]$ and simply expanding the square in the exponent.

Comment: That part I understand, what I don't understand are the later parts with the distribution of the summations, and the negative sign.